# Is this quote actually in the Gospel of Mark?

Tags: gospel-of-mark

In a chapter heading to Tom Cheethams *The World Inside Out: Henry Corbin & Islamic Myticism* the following is quoted:

> He who believes a lot
>
> Experiences a lot
>
> -- Peasant woman from the Gospel of Mark

I'm not overly familiar with the this Gospel but it sounds rather too colloquial to be Biblical language. Is it actually a reference and who is this peasant woman? If not, how do I make sense of this?

(Its pointed out in a footnote that this was quote was taken from Hans Peter Deurer *Dreamtime: concerning the boundary between wilderness and civilisation*).

Answer (score 1):

No, the only women who talk in the Gospel of Mark were:

- Woman with hemorrhage
- Herod's sister-in-law
- Maid asking St. Peter if he knew Jesus

If this is just someone being philosophical, but not specifically Biblical, I'd imagine they're talking about the first person, whom Jesus healed when she touched "the hem of His garment".  As Jesus said "her faith has healed her".

- https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+5&version=NASB